# Sort Array of Dictionaries by Key Value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries and I want to sort them alphabetically by the "itemName" key in each dictionary. How can I do this in Swift?

I want to sort the itemsArray.

```
let array = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("Collections") as! [[String : AnyObject]]
        let collectionsDictionary = array[0]
        itemsArray = collectionsDictionary[self.title!] as! [[String : AnyObject]]


        for dictionary in itemsArray {
            itemNames.append(dictionary["itemName"] as! String)
            itemUPC.append(dictionary["UPC"] as! String)
            pricePaid.append(dictionary["pricePaid"] as! String)
            currentPrice.append(dictionary["currentPrice"] as! String)
            model.append(dictionary["model"] as! String)
            if (dictionary["image"] != nil) {
                imagesArray.append(dictionary["image"] as! PFFile)
            } else {
                imagesArray.append(nil)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can resort to `NSArray`'s `sortUsingDescriptors` functionality:

```
let sortedArray = (itemsArray as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemName", ascending: true)]) as [[String:AnyObject]]
```

**Swift > 3**

```
let sortedArray = (itemsArray as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemName", ascending: true)]) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
```

Not very Swift-ish, and you lose the type safety, but it does it's job.

And btw, you have a lot of forced casts in your code, which have the potential of crashing your app, you should consider switching to optional ones instead.

Comment: Thanks! It works even though it's not the ideal solution.

Comment: Thank u ..very nice solution.

Comment: this helped me to sort the array of places according to their distance to the user, thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Probably something like this, using `sort`:

```
let sortedArray = itemsArray.sort { $0["itemName"] < $1["itemName"] }
```

where "$0" and "$1" represent respectively, in the array, each dictionary and its successor.

---

If the compiler complains about the types because it doesn't know that the value for this key is a String, you can cast like this (as said by @Cristik in the comments):

```
let sortedArray = itemsArray.sort { ($0["itemName"] as? String) < ($1["itemName"] as? String) }
```

Comment: I get an "Expected Type" error.  

let sortedArray = itemsArray.sort { $0["itemName"] as String < $1["itemName"] as String }

Comment: It looks Awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
let descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemName", ascending: true)
let sortedResults: NSArray = favArray.sortedArray(using: [descriptor]) as NSArray
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an array of dictionaries and i am sorting my array with alphabetically by the "firstname" key in each dictionary. You can also sort your array by just putting your array name in this code and your keyName

/*

```
 let descriptor: NSSortDescriptor =  NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstname", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
 let sortedResults: NSArray = yourArrayName.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])

  self.user_Array = NSMutableArray(array: sortedResults)
```

*/

Hopefully it helps you.

Comment: Am using the selector value, you are not . So how this is same?

Answer (score 0):

'$'
/// items is array of dictionary
/*

```
let items: [[String: Any]] = [
   ["itemName":"ZZ_Item", "itemDescription":"Homer"],
   ["itemName":"AA_Item", "itemDescription":"Marge"],
   ["itemName":"VV_Item", "itemDescription":"Bart"],
   ["itemName":"BB_Item", "itemDescription":"Lisa"],
   ["itemName":"XY_Item", "itemDescription":"Maggie"],
   ["itemName":"CC_Item", "itemDescription":"Ned"]
]
print(items)
```

*/
/// O/P  un_sorted array

/// 
[["itemName": "ZZ_Item", "itemDescription": "Homer"], ["itemName": "AA_Item", "itemDescription": "Marge"], ["itemName": "VV_Item", "itemDescription": "Bart"], ["itemName": "BB_Item", "itemDescription": "Lisa"], ["itemName": "XY_Item", "itemDescription": "Maggie"], ["itemName": "CC_Item", "itemDescription": "Ned"]]

/// sort array by itemsName key

```
func itemsSort(p1:[String:Any], p2:[String:Any]) -> Bool {
    guard let s1 = p1["itemName"] as? String, let s2 = p2["itemName"] as? String else {
        return false
    }
    return s1 < s2
}

let sortedItemsArray = items.sorted { itemsSort(p1:$0, p2:$1) }
print(sortedItemsArray)
```

//// O/P sorted array

[["itemName": "AA_Item", "itemDescription": "Marge"], ["itemName": "BB_Item", "itemDescription": "Lisa"], ["itemName": "CC_Item", "itemDescription": "Ned"], ["itemName": "VV_Item", "itemDescription": "Bart"], ["itemName": "XY_Item", "itemDescription": "Maggie"], ["itemName": "ZZ_Item", "itemDescription": "Homer"]]