# Sorting NSMutableArray depending on priority

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

I have a NSMutableArray of Dictionary.

```
dic1 = ["user":"Smith","points":12,"lastPoints":4,online:3MonthsAgo(NSDate)]
dic2 = ["user":"Mike","points":22,"lastPoints":3,online:2MonthsAgo(NSDate)]
dic3 = ["user":"Mark","points":22,"lastRank":5,online:now(NSDate)]
dic4 = ["user":"Jay","points":16,"lastPoints":2,online:2minutes(NSDate)]
dic5 = ["user":"Alex","points":13,"lastPoints":5,online:1hr(NSDate)]
dic6 = ["user":"Peter","points":22,"lastPoints":3,online:2days(NSDate)]
```

I want to rearrage this in 3 ways,
First users with top points will show first
So

```
Mike:22
Mark:22
Peter:22
Jay:16
Alex:13
Smith:12
```

now that i did using

```
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "points", ascending: false)
```

the next thing I want to do this sort this users again depending on **lastPoints** example

```
Mark:22:5
Mike:22:3
Peter:22:3
Jay:16:2
Alex:13:5
Smith:12:4
```

and then sort Mike's and Peter's position in array depending on their last online date.
Now when i try

```
 let sortAgain = NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastPoints", ascending: false) and then
let sortAgain2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "online", ascending: false)
```

It deletes the sort of **points** that i did before and sorts everything again depending on lastPoints.
I want it to sort them depending on points and then see if points are equal, sort those points data depending on lastPoints. And if lastPoints are equal sort these equal datas depeding on "Online" date.

Comment: You told us what you want. But you forgot to told us what you tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Array of Dictionaries by Key Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745802/sort-array-of-dictionaries-by-key-value)

Comment: I'm stuck sorting them depeding on lastPoints and Online dates, because when i try , it sorts them but Mark:22 is not on top,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let result = arr.sort {
    let p0 = $0["points"] as! Int
    let p1 = $1["points"] as! Int

    let lp0 = $0["lastPoints"] as! Int
    let lp1 = $1["lastPoints"] as! Int

    let online0 = $0["online"] as! NSDate
    let online1 = $1["online"] as! NSDate

    if p0 != p1 {
        return p0 > p1
    } else if lp0 != lp1 {
        return lp0 > lp1
    } else {
        return online0.timeIntervalSince1970 > online1.timeIntervalSince1970
    }
}
```

Comment: My eyes, so many forced casts :) Note that forced casts (forced stuff in general in Swift) have the undesired effect of crashing the app when you're least expecting.

Comment: @Code Different is there any similar function in android ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `sort` (or `sortInPlace`) function, where you can specify your custom sorting block. For example, if you put all your `Dictionaries` into an `Array`, you could do the following:

```
array.sort { (dict1, dict2) -> Bool in
    if let p1 = dictionary1["points"] as? Int, let p2 = dictionary2["points"] as? Int {
        if let l1 = dictionary1["lastPoints"] as? Int, let l2 = dictionary2["lastPoints"] as? Int where p1 == p2 {
            return l1 > l2
        }
        return p1 > p2
    }
    return false
}
```

You will have to make a suitable implementation yourself, but the concept should work for you.

Comment: so i will have to compare all the objects to each and everyone and then get a new array out of it?

Comment: you don't have to run it for each pair. the `sort` function does it for you, you just specify the block, where `dict1` and `dict2` in my example are two given items from the array at a given point of sorting process. `sort` function with return a new array that is sorted. `sortInPlace` will replace the array with a sorted one.