# why the sequence of swift2.0's dictionary like this?

Tags: swift, dictionary, tuples

The code is as follows:

```
let values = ["small":30, "middle":50, "large":70]
var result = "Hello"
for a in values {
    result += a.0
}
print(result)
```

and the result is:

```
Hellomiddlesmalllarge
```

I thought the result should be:

```
Hellosmallmiddlelarge
```

Could anyone tell me the reason? Thanks

Comment: A Swift dictionary is stored as an *unordered* sequence. This is working as expected. :)

Comment: Thank you ! Is there anything I can do to change the sequence in dictionary ?

Comment: No because a dictionary is not ordered, so you can't change its order... it doesn't have one. :) But you can always extract the keys or keys and values into an array and then sort them, there's already many posts about this on SO. Have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745802/sort-array-of-dictionaries-by-key-value/34745863#34745863) for sorting values, but you could also do it for the keys.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Good night

Comment: It's not particularly related to Swift 2. Key/value based collection types  are unordered in all languages.

Comment: @vadian: There are sorted dictionaries in many languages, e.g. `std::map` in C++, `TreeMap` in Java, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary has no order. Whatever implicit order you get when iterating over it is implementation-dependent. [SwiftStub](http://swiftstub.com/) (running on OS X) and [IBM Swift Sandbox](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl) (Linux) give different orders. Both are valid because the standard did not dictate any order.

If you want to order the dictionary by its value, you must sort explicitly:

```
let values = ["small":30, "middle":50, "large":70]
var result = "Hello"

values.sort {
    $0.1 < $1.1
}.forEach {
    result += " " + $0.0
}

print(result)
```