# Sorting an dictionary of dictionary in swift3 based on particular key

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I am receiving the following response from API, I need to sort this dictionary of dictionary based on the displayOrder key. So as per the below code you can see currently the order is [SALE, OFFER, DISCOUNT, SOLD] which I want to be in order [SALE, SOLD, OFFER, DISCOUNT].

```
["SALE": {
    displayOrder = 1;
    segId = 2;
    chg = 2;
}, "OFFER": {
    displayOrder = 3;
    segId = 4;
    chg = 2;
}, "DISCOUNT": {
    displayOrder = 4;
    segId = 1;
    chg = 1;
}, "SOLD": {
    displayOrder = 2;
    segId = 2;
    chg = 1;
}]
```

Comment: This actually looks like a dictionary of dictionaries, not an array of dictionaries.

Comment: If you're actually trying to sort an array of dictionaries, this question is a duplicate.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745802/sort-array-of-dictionaries-by-key-value

Comment: @DavidBerry yes my bad, pretty new in in this actually

Comment: @DavidBerry no i am not looking for array of dictionary, that would have been easier for me as well. I am looking out for this particular nested scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Simple sort it with `sorted` function like:

```
let dic = ["SALE": [
    "displayOrder" : 1,
    "segId" : 2,
    "chg" : 2,
    ], "OFFER": [
        "displayOrder" : 3,
        "segId" : 4,
        "chg" : 2,
    ], "DISCOUNT": [
        "displayOrder" : 4,
        "segId" : 1,
        "chg" : 1,
    ], "SOLD": [
        "displayOrder" : 2,
        "segId" : 2,
        "chg" : 1,
    ]]

dic.sorted { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    lhs.value["displayOrder"]! < rhs.value["displayOrder"]!
}
```

Comment: An important note is that this is actually sorting the key/value tuples in the the dictionary and returns`[(key: String, value: [String : Int])]`  Ie., an array of tuples.

Comment: Depending on the source you may also need to do some type casting and you should really fear the `!`

Comment: @DavidBerry yes i agree ! needs to be managed and handling the type casting is another pain