# Sorting array of dictionaries based on dates in dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

1. My question is particular for swift 4 and later. I have an array containing no of dictionaries in it and those dictionaries have some key value pair storing dates in it and I need to sort this array in descending order. See my code below:

   ```
   var notificationsDataArray = [[String:Any]]()
   for (index,notificationDict) in allNotifications.enumerated() 
   {
      if let dict = notificationDict.value as? [String: Any] {
         self.notificationsDataArray.append(dict)
      }
   }
   ```
2. The dictionary of type `[String:Any]` inside my `notificationsDataArray` have key-value pairs as `["received_amt":100, "received_date": "2019-06-03T19:35:28"]` and I want this `notificationsDataArray` sorting by `received_date` in **`descending`** order. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you have a look at the various solutions in [Sort Array of Dictionaries by Key Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745802/sort-array-of-dictionaries-by-key-value) ?

Comment: Yes. But I have found array of dates sorted directly, and I need to sort by dictionaries inside my array. I need exact code for that.

Comment: Please note that your date strings can be sorted as strings. No need to convert them to `Date` to perform the sort. This works because your date strings have a sortable format.

Comment: I want to know how I can iterate all dictionaries inside my notificationsDataArray and sort them in descending order either I need to convert my dateString into Date object or not. I just need the piece of code in swift 4 or later.